# Linearly independent family from a nilpotent map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $\psi: V \to V$ be a linear map that $ψ^k \neq  0$ and $ψ^{k+1}=0$ (where $k>0$). To prove that there is an element $x \in  V$ such that $\{x, ψ (x), \dots, ψ^k (x)\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Any $x$ that isn't in the kernel of $\psi^k$ will do.  Consider taking the equation $\sum_{i=0}^k a_i\psi^i x = 0$ and applying an appropriate power of $\psi$ to both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in V\setminus {0\ } |\ \psi^k(x)\neq0 \Longrightarrow \psi^i(x)\neq 0 \forall i=0,...,k$, because $Ker(\psi^i)\subseteq Ker(\psi^{i+1})$.

Let $a_0,...,a_k\in K\ | \ \sum_{i=0}^ka_i\psi^i(x)=0, $ where $\psi^0=id_V.$

$\Longrightarrow \psi^k(\sum_{i=0}^ka_i\psi^i(x))=0\ \Longrightarrow a_0x=0$ or $a_0=0$.

$\Longrightarrow \sum_{i=0}^ka_i\psi^i(x)=\sum_{i=1}^ka_i\psi^i(x)=0 \ \Longrightarrow \psi^{k-1}(\sum_{i=0}^ka_i\psi^i(x))=0\ \Longrightarrow a_1=0.$

.
.
.

So you can show $a_i=0 \forall i=0,...,k$ or the set is linearly independent.

$$\Box$$